# Problem in adding product with add to cart button in opencart

Tags: amazon-web-services, opencart, e-commerce, opencart2.x, opencart-3

Add to cart button is not working in my website kartforu.com based on opencart. when inspect element in google chrome it showing ("uncaught type error button is not function"). this is the link of website https://kartforu.com

error shown in attached screenshot also

[here is image...error is red underlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAbgL.jpg)

Comment: It looks like a jQuery issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Jquery multiple times which is creating the issue. Once you keep only one then it starts working.

[image]